# What's the best way to read code in CWEB format in Windows?

Tags: literate-programming, knuth

Donald Knuth has [a large number of programs to read](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/programs.html) on his page. But they are mostly in a "strange" CWEB format...

What could be the best way to make them appropriately readable in Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Less than five minutes of Googling brings this up: http://www.literateprogramming.com/cweb_download.html

Comment: Is there a better way, without the need to install TeX on my machine?

Comment: Given that the CWEB source is written in a TeX variant, I'd say probably not.  However, TeX is free and not particularly bloated, so having to install it is no big deal.

Answer (score 4):

The way I find most convenient to read a `CWEB` program is by running `cweave` ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cweave)) on the `.w` source file to generate a `.tex` file, and then running `pdfetex` to get a nice *hyperlinked* PDF. Pictorially:

```
     `.W SOURCE   ----(cweave)---->   .TEX   ----(pdfetex)---->   PDF`
```

As you would be aware, the structure of a `CWEB` program is itself sort of hyperlinked (with sections referring other sections). Having a nice, linked PDF is a sheer pleasure to read, specially if the programs have been written by Don Knuth himself!

The following setup would involve some effort on your part (and MBs of download), but I hope you'll like the final result:

- Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (for any serious Windows programmer, I think installing cygwin is a no-brainer). Make sure you install the *Typesetting* related packages (tex, pdfetex, amstex and all that). If cygwin gives you an option to install CWEB, do that too.
- If you don't get `cweave` and `ctangle` with cygwin, download the [sources](http://www.literateprogramming.com/cweb.tar.gz) and build/install those.

Once cygwin and cweb have been installed, do the following to any `.w` program you wish to study (I'm taking an example of `bdd12.w`):

- Run `cweave` like so: `cweave bdd12.w`
  This should generate a `bdd12.tex` file.
- Then run `pdfetex` like so: `pdfetex bdd12.tex`
  This should get you a neat, cross-referenced PDF. The generated PDF also has an index of symbols at the end (and some more crossreferencing data), so you can quickly jump to their definitions.